# How to convert this bootstrap to react bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, navbar, react-bootstrap

I am having a website which was created using bootstrap. now i am migrating my project to react. So, I was trying to use `react-bootstrap`. can someone help me to translate this Nav bar code written in bootstrap to `react-bootstrap`. I have tried changing `class` to `className` but it didnt work.

```
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark ftco_navbar bg-dark ftco-navbar-light" id="ftco-navbar">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/index"><img src="{% static 'lab/images/logos/newlogo.png' %}" /></a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#ftco-nav"
                    aria-controls="ftco-nav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="oi oi-menu"></span> Menu
                </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="ftco-nav">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item active"><a href="/index" class="nav-link"
                                onMouseOver="this.style.color='#A41034'" onmouseout="this.style.color='black'"
                                style="text-transform: capitalize;">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item active"><a href="/research" class="nav-link"
                                onMouseOver="this.style.color='#A41034'" onmouseout="this.style.color='black'"
                                style="text-transform: capitalize;">Research</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item active"><a href="/publications" class="nav-link"
                                onMouseOver="this.style.color='#A41034'" onmouseout="this.style.color='black'"
                                style="text-transform: capitalize;">Publications</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item active dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="/team" id="navbarDropdown" role="button"
                                onMouseOver="this.style.color='#A41034'" onmouseout="this.style.color='black'"
                                data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"
                                style="text-transform: capitalize;">
                                People
                            </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="/pi" onMouseOver="this.style.color='#A41034'"
                                    onmouseout="this.style.color='black'">Principal Investigators</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="/researchers"
                                    onMouseOver="this.style.color='#A41034'"
                                    onmouseout="this.style.color='black'">Senior Scientists</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="/phd_students"
                                    onMouseOver="this.style.color='#A41034'" onmouseout="this.style.color='black'">PhD/Masters
                                    Students</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="/students" onMouseOver="this.style.color='#A41034'"
                                    onmouseout="this.style.color='black'">Research Trainees</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="/alumni" onMouseOver="this.style.color='#A41034'"
                                    onmouseout="this.style.color='black'">Alumni</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item active"><a href="/contact" class="nav-link"
                                onMouseOver="this.style.color='#A41034'" onmouseout="this.style.color='black'"
                                style="text-transform: capitalize;">Projects</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item active"><a href="/joinus" class="nav-link"
                                onMouseOver="this.style.color='#A41034'" onmouseout="this.style.color='black'"
                                style="text-transform: capitalize;">Join
                                Us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please make sure you include bootstrap CDN or install bootstrap properly?
And also make sure you import bootstrap.
According to your code, it should work.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). -  [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers/32318749)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32318839)